# Prepared food barrels don't have a category in the trade depot

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I don't see a category for prepared meals in the trade depot? I can find them by searching [All] though

v0.42.03

Answer (score 3):

There isn't one. They are under [Barrels] if they've been stored in barrels, so you can search for "prepared", and then just look at the [Barrels] category. It should then only contain meals (that have been stored in barrels).